# argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.7, tkinter-entry

I wrote this code to calculate for bmi using the tkinter. but if i run it, it will but gives float() argument must be a string or a number not 'nonetype'

i tried using get() function

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def bmi_cal():
    BMI = round(weight / height)
    bmi_info = user_name + ",Your BMI is " + str(BMI) + "."
    if BMI < 18.5:
        print(user_name + ", your BMI is " + str(BMI) + ",you are possibly 
underweight or malnourished.")
    elif 18.5 < BMI < 24.29:
        print(user_name + ", your BMI is " + str(BMI) + ", you are within 
healthy range.")
    elif 25.0 < BMI < 29.9:
        print(user_name + ", your BMI is " + str(BMI) + ", you are 
overweight which is unhealthy. \nPlease see a nutritionist.")
    else:
        print(user_name + ", your BMI is " + str(BMI) + ", you are possibly 
obese, please see a nutritionist.")


a= Tk()
n= 'tahoma', 14, 'bold'
Label(a, text='Username', padx=25, font=(n)).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
User_name = Entry(a, width=25 ).grid(row=0,column=1)
Label(a, text='Your_Weight', padx=25, font=(n)).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
weight = ttk.Entry(a, width=25,).grid(row=1,column=1)
Label(a, text='Your_Weight', padx=25, font=(n)).grid(row=2,sticky=W)
height = ttk.Entry(a, width=25).grid(row=2,column=1)
Button(a,text='Calculate', font=(n),command= bmi_cal).grid(row=3, column=1)





a.mainloop()
```

the result was to be weight /height.

Answer (score 0):

your definition needs to contain the variables you wish to pass to it:

```
def bmi_cal(arg1, arg22, ...):
```

besides that, you probably want to put your UI setup in to a class as best practice

EDIT:

I cant test this right now as i don't have tkinter on the machine im commenting from. But i believe it would look something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class bmi_calculator():

    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def session(self):
        n= 'tahoma', 14, 'bold'
        Label(a, text='Username', padx=25, font=(n)).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
        user_name = Entry(a, width=25 ).grid(row=0,column=1)
        Label(a, text='Your_Weight', padx=25, font=(n)).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
        weight = ttk.Entry(a, width=25,).grid(row=1,column=1)
        Label(a, text='Your_Weight', padx=25, font=(n)).grid(row=2,sticky=W)
        height = ttk.Entry(a, width=25).grid(row=2,column=1)
        Button(a,text='Calculate', font=(n),command= self.bmi_cal(weight, height, user_name)).grid(row=3, column=1)
        a.mainloop()        

    @staticmethod
    def bmi_cal(weight, height, user_name):
        BMI = round(weight / height)
        bmi_info = user_name + ",Your BMI is " + str(BMI) + "."
        if BMI < 18.5:
            print(user_name + ", your BMI is " + str(BMI) + ",you are possibly underweight or malnourished.")
        elif 18.5 < BMI < 24.29:
            print(user_name + ", your BMI is " + str(BMI) + ", you are within healthy range.")
        elif 25.0 < BMI < 29.9:
            print(user_name + ", your BMI is " + str(BMI) + ", you are overweight which is unhealthy. \nPlease see a nutritionist.")
        else:
            print(user_name + ", your BMI is " + str(BMI) + ", you are possibly obese, please see a nutritionist.")


window = bmi_calculator()
window.session()
```

Comment: thanks bro, but when i ran the code, it gives error ( a is not defined)

Comment: its not going to work if you expect it to be some pre prepared package for you to run. also read my note for the edit. do some debugging and see if you can fix it yourself. what does "a is not defined" tell you?

Comment: a is suppose to be among the properties of the label, and assigned to Tk(). sorry what does window.session() do?. i even tried debugging it still gave my back float() argument must be number or string not nonetype

Comment: there are many variables in the session function that you have not defined, python will not run unless you parse valid variables. the window.session() call is just a wrapper to start the tkinter GUI

Comment: please can you help me list the variable in session function that i have not defined.

Comment: a needs to be : a= Tk() and there is no definition for the variable "w"

Comment: i did assign a=Tk() before the class, and W means west, it help in positioning the dialog box

Comment: i have updated the class but still giving float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: the answer to your problem is in the error. learn how to debug your code yourself. you wont learn anything otherwise